# Where to put gtfs and osm data for the open trip planner?

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I am trying to use open trip planner and I’m using the src/client/index.html to view the gtfs and osm data.  What file do I edit to point the data to use for otp?  Where do I put the gtfs and osm data so I can view it through the index.html provided in OTP 2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you put the GTFS and OSM data as long as they are together in the same folder.

e.g. create an `otp` folder inside your user folder and copy across the GTFS and OSM data: `home/username/otp`

Then fire up your OTP instance, which will compile the GTFS/OSM data into a graph object and serve on localhost:8080.

```
java -Xmx2G -jar otp-2.0.0-rc1-shaded.jar --build --serve /home/username/otp
```

There are more options available on the basic tutorial of the official documentation:
http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/